# Tensorflow.NET on Ubuntu: libtensorflow not found

Tags: c#, tensorflow, ubuntu, .net-core, tf.keras

We're trying to run a simple model using Tensorflow.NET and Tensorflow.Keras in a .NET 6 application. It works flawlessly on windows. We have installed SciSharp.TensorFlow.Redist-Linux-GPU and SciSharp.TensorFlow.Redist-Windows-GPU, and it works on Windows.

On Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS however (provided by jupyterhub with a GPU and python+tensorflow 2.10), as soon as we run it with the GPU package, it crashes with the exception mentioning 'tensorflow' not found, libtensorflow: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Any idea what I can do? I looked at the output directory theres rutimes/linux64/tensorflow.dll with ~455MB so I assumed the GPU-enabled library is indeed present.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version number?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, codename focal